# Selecting top results from SQL Count query, including table join - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, filter, count

I have this query currently, which selects the top "number of pickups" in descending order. I need to filter only the top 10 rows/highest numbers though. How can I do this?

I have tried adding 'WHERE ROWNUM <= 10' at the bottom, to no avail.

```
SELECT customer.company_name, COUNT (item.pickup_reference) as "Number of Pickups" 
FROM customer
JOIN item ON (customer.reference_no=item.pickup_reference) 
GROUP BY customer.company_name, item.pickup_reference
ORDER BY COUNT (customer.company_name) DESC;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subquery it for the rownum to work.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT customer.company_name, COUNT (item.pickup_reference) as "Number of Pickups" 
FROM customer
JOIN item ON (customer.reference_no=item.pickup_reference) 
GROUP BY customer.company_name, item.pickup_reference
ORDER BY COUNT (customer.company_name) DESC
) 
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

You could alternatively use ranking functions, but given the relative simplicity of this, I'm not sure whether I would.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by using the rank is something like this :

```
select customer.company_name, COUNT (item.pickup_reference) from (
    select distinct customer.company_name, COUNT (item.pickup_reference) ,
    rank() over ( order by count(item.pickup_reference) desc) rnk 
    from customer
    JOIN item ON (customer.reference_no=item.pickup_reference) 
    group by customer.company_name, item.pickup_reference
    order by COUNT (customer.company_name) )
where rnk < 10
```

Using the 'rownum' to get the top result doesn't give the expected result, because it get the 10 first rows which are not ordred, and then order them (Please notify this on a comment on Andrew's response, I don't have the right to add the comment) .